# Getting Video or Audio Duration From Cloud URL(Amazon S3 URL)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, media, duration

I need the media length from Audio and Video URL which is stored in Amazon S3 Cloud storage. I have tried wmplib and directshow lib but both are used to get the duration or length when the file is stored temporarily in file system. I need to get the media length by directly passing the cloud URL.

I have also used Windows APICodePack.Shell library. All these libraries can be used to get duration of a locally stored file.

How this can be achieved?

**Using Windows APICodePack.Shell**

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
ShellFile so = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file);
            double nanoseconds;
            double.TryParse(so.Properties.System.Media.Duration.Value.ToString(), 
            out nanoseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("NanaoSeconds: {0}", nanoseconds);
```

**Using WMPLib**

```
WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
    IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia(filePath);
    return mediaInfo.durationString
```